# Read an instruction line by line java

Tags: java, file-io, java.util.scanner

I have a set of instructions in a text file:

```
LoadA 0

LoadB 1

Add

Store 0

LoadA 2

etc...
```

I know I can use Scanner and hasNextLine but not sure how to implement this and have the instructions read and understood.

Comment: SO is not a place for making people to do your **Homework** , `Learn` yourself , Solve it and then if you face any problem this society is always there to help

Comment: try to read tutorials first!!

Comment: Neeraj Jain, I've been trying to solve it. I don't know how to implement it. I need help for this one part with is about 1/15th of the entire assignment. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As much as the people above would like you to do this on your own I will answer this question because I remember how difficult it was to learn. As long as you learn from the and don't just copy them this should be useful.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);   //read from the System.in
while (sc.hasNextLine()) { //this will continue to itterate until it runs out
     String[] x = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
     //this takes your input and puts it into a string array where there is a 
     //space e.g. ["LoadA", "0"]
}
```

I hope this helps. You are still required to solve the problem. You now have the ability to get the content now. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner inFile = null;
try 
    {
       // Create a scanner to read the file, file name is parameter
        inFile = new Scanner (new File("whatever.txt"));
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
        System.out.println ("File not found!");
        // Stop program if no file found
        System.exit (0);
        }
```

then,

```
while(inFile.hasNextLine()){
    (some variable) = inFile.nextLine();
    (do something to that variable);
}
```

if this doesn't solve the question, I would recommend taking a look at http://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/Java_files.html